# Exception in regexp_instr using clob uncatchable?

Tags: oracle, exception

The zero is illegal, should be a one, but the real problem is that the exception is not catchable.  It bubbles to top and "caught it" is never printed.  The d()'s just write to dbms output.  The exception is catchable if i change the clob to a varchar2.  The fact that the exception is uncatchable is a bug right?  The exception is ora-01428 argument '0' is out of range.

```
declare
    v int;
    p_in clob := 'i think i can init like this';     
begin
    d('started');
    v := regexp_instr(p_in, 'some_regexp', 0);
    d('it worked');
exception when others then
    d('caught it');
end;
```

ya know, just know reporting a bug to a company should feel like more of a gift to the company not a torturous experience to the user.  30 minutes i goofed around trying to create an account and enter an oracle bug, entering same stuff multiple times.  forget it.  what happened to kiss.  how about anonymous bugs.  cmon oracle.

Comment: Unable to reproduce. I replaced the `d()` calls to `dbms_output.put_line` and it gives the following output: `started caught it`

Comment: What do you get if you replace the exception handler with `dbms_output.put_line(SQLERRM);`?

Comment: What is `d`? Maybe there's a bug in your procedure...

Comment: maybe i should have put rant its own separate entry but please dont just rm it and enlarge /dev/null/emotions, its big enough already.  i dare say the rant was more important overall to the success of oracle although its perhaps misplaced.

Comment: Changed the d()s to dbms call and added SQLERRM but exception is still uncaught throwing same Ora-01428 .  Using 10.2.0.4 which may be version specific to the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Oracle XE (10.2.0.1), the following fails with an unhandled exception at line 1

```
declare
    v int;
    p_in clob := 'i think i can init like this';
begin
    v := regexp_instr(p_in, 'some_regexp', 0);
exception 
  when others then
    dbms_output.put_line('caught');
end;    
/
```

Because it is at line 1, it can't even enter the declare section, so it isn't getting caught be the exception handler..

```
 declare
     v int;
     p_in clob := 'i think i can init like this'; begin
     select regexp_instr(p_in, 'some_regexp', 0) into v from dual;
 end;
 /
```

errors at line 5 and

```
declare
    v int;
    p_in clob := 'i think i can init like this';
begin
    select regexp_instr(p_in, 'some_regexp', 0) into v from dual;
exception 
  when others then
    dbms_output.put_line('caught');
end;    
/
```

catches the error.

=========================================================================
PS. It looks like the issue is down to STANDARD.REGEXP_INSTR

```
select package_name, object_name, overload,  argument_name, 
       position, sequence, data_type, in_out, pls_type
from all_arguments 
where object_name = 'REGEXP_INSTR' order by overload, position
```

indicates two procedures, one for VARCHAR2 and one for CLOB. The CLOB one has a NUMBER/INTEGER as the POSITION parameter while the VARCHAR2 has a BINARY_INTEGER/PLS_INTEGER. I guess the PLS_INTEGER isn't big enough to hold the a value for a very large CLOB of gigabytes etcs.

Comment: Verified that changing the direct assignment to v into a "select into" allows the exception to be caught.  Not sure i understand why.  I am using 10.2.0.4.  Thanks for this info.